# Call to function not working

Tags: python, function

I'm trying to make a simple Python game of "Higher or lower" where the user thinks of a number between 1 and 100 and the computer tries to guess it.  For every guess, the user types 'H', 'L', or 'C' (for "Higher", "Lower", or "Correct" respectively).  The computer's first guess is always 50.  Here's the code:

```
first_guess = 50
print("I guess {}".format(first_guess))
h_l_c = input("Higher, lower, or correct?: ").strip().lower()

def guess_c():
    win = "I WON!"
    if h_l_c == "c":
        return win

guess_c()
```

So anyway, I run this and I get:

```
I guess 50.
Higher, lower, or correct?:
```

I then type c.  Now, as I understand it, because `h_l_c` has been defined as `"c"`, the function `guess_c()` should run and Python should execute the function and print `"I WON!"`. Unfortunately, nothing is happening.

I'm very new to Python and I've been struggling to understand functions for a while.  Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Where are your calling `print` in your function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `guess_c` is running well, but notice that you are 'returning' a value. Instead, just print it inside the if block. Something like this:

```
def guess_c():
    win = "I WON!"
    if h_l_c == "c":
        print win
```

Comment: or better yet, `print(guess_c())`

Answer (score 1):

You're returning `win` when you call `guess_c` which doesn't print your string:

```
first_guess = 50
print("I guess {}".format(first_guess))
h_l_c = input("Higher, lower, or correct?: ").strip().lower()

def guess_c():
    win = "I WON!"
    if h_l_c == "c":
         print(win)                # Change return win with print(win) 

guess_c()                          # or print(guess_c())
```

You're not printing the results returned by `guess_c()` call, you're just returning `win` and thus `win` string wont be written to stdout.